# Trying to convert CakePHP Find() to MySql statement

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have run into difficulty converting a CakePHP find() call into a MySQL query.

The Cake query is structured as follows:

```
    $contain = array(
            'BookingOrder'=>array('conditions'=>array('BookingOrder.cancelled'=>0)), // where room not booked
                'Room'=>array('fields'=>array('Room.id','Room.title','Room.no_of_rooms','Room.list_no'),'conditions'=>array('Room.deleted'=>0,'Room.enabled'=>1)),
                'Price'
                );

    $this->Availability->contain($contain); 
                $conditions = array('Availability.date BETWEEN ? AND ? ' => array($date_start.' 00:00:00',$date_last.' 23:59:59')); 
                $availability = $this->Availability->find('all',array('order'=>'Availability.date ASC, Room.list_no', 'conditions'=>$conditi

ons));
```

So far I have the following:

```
SELECT availabilities.* FROM availabilities WHERE availabilities.date BETWEEN '2012-03-16 00:00:00' AND '2012-03-18 00:00:00' ORDER BY availabilities.date ASC
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

I turned on Debug mode and the output is as follows (Sorry for such a lengthy listing):

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `acos`       7   7   5
4   SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `aros_acos`      7   7   5
5   SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `bookings`       36  36  6
6   SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `booking_orders`     17  17  5
7   SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `rates`      24  24  5
8   SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `prices`     4   4   4
9   SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `availabilities`     4   4   4
10  SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `rooms`      14  14  5
11  SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `add_on_raterooms`       4   4   4
12  SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `add_ons`        16  16  5
13  SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `add_on_categories`      10  10  5
14  SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `add_on_purchases`       9   9   7
15  SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `rates_rooms`        5   5   5
16  SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `availabilities_booking_orders`      3   3   5
17  SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `corporate_accounts`     22  22  5
18  SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `users`      24  24  6
19  SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `groups`     4   4   5
20  SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `loyalty_histories`      5   5   6
21  SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `corporate_accounts_rates`       3   3   4
22  SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `survey_responses`       9   9   5
23  SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `survey_questions`       13  13  5
24  SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `surveys`        9   9   5
25  SELECT `Rate`.`id`, `Rate`.`id_ref`, `Rate`.`title`, `Rate`.`short_description`, `Rate`.`description`, `Rate`.`price_quote_as`, `Rate`.`adult_supplement`, `Rate`.`child_supplement`, `Rate`.`supplement`, `Rate`.`minimum_stay`, `Rate`.`maximum_stay`, `Rate`.`imagefile`, `Rate`.`enabled`, `Rate`.`special_offer`, `Rate`.`list_no`, `Rate`.`availability`, `Rate`.`valid_from`, `Rate`.`valid_to`, `Rate`.`is_corporate`, `Rate`.`created`, `Rate`.`updated`, `Rate`.`deleted`, `Rate`.`dirname`, `Rate`.`basename` FROM `rates` AS `Rate` WHERE `Rate`.`enabled` = 1 AND `Rate`.`is_corporate` = 0 AND `Rate`.`minimum_stay` <= 71 AND `Rate`.`valid_from` < '2012-04-16 00:00:00' AND `Rate`.`valid_to` > '2012-06-25 00:00:00' AND ((`Rate`.`maximum_stay` = 0) OR (`Rate`.`maximum_stay` >= 71)) AND `Rate`.`deleted` = 0 ORDER BY `Rate`.`list_no` ASC        4   4   1
26  SELECT `Room`.`id`, `Room`.`title`, `Room`.`max_adults`, `Room`.`max_children`, `RatesRoom`.`id`, `RatesRoom`.`rate_id`, `RatesRoom`.`room_id`, `RatesRoom`.`dirname`, `RatesRoom`.`basename` FROM `rooms` AS `Room` JOIN `rates_rooms` AS `RatesRoom` ON (`RatesRoom`.`rate_id` IN (35, 29, 15, 10) AND `RatesRoom`.`room_id` = `Room`.`id`)       31  31  1
27  SELECT `Room`.`id`, `Room`.`title`, `Room`.`description`, `Room`.`no_of_rooms`, `Room`.`min_adults`, `Room`.`max_adults`, `Room`.`max_children`, `Room`.`dirname`, `Room`.`basename` FROM `rooms` AS `Room` WHERE `Room`.`enabled` = 1 AND `Room`.`deleted` = 0 ORDER BY `Room`.`list_no` ASC       9   9   1
28  SELECT `Rate`.`id`, `Rate`.`title`, `Rate`.`supplement`, `Rate`.`price_quote_as`, `RatesRoom`.`id`, `RatesRoom`.`rate_id`, `RatesRoom`.`room_id`, `RatesRoom`.`dirname`, `RatesRoom`.`basename` FROM `rates` AS `Rate` JOIN `rates_rooms` AS `RatesRoom` ON (`RatesRoom`.`room_id` IN (27, 12, 15, 14, 11, 16, 13, 17, 18) AND `RatesRoom`.`rate_id` = `Rate`.`id`) WHERE `Rate`.`is_corporate` = 0 ORDER BY `Rate`.`list_no` ASC       219 219 3
29  SELECT `Availability`.`id`, `Availability`.`room_id`, `Availability`.`date`, `Availability`.`amount`, `Room`.`id`, `Room`.`title`, `Room`.`no_of_rooms`, `Room`.`list_no` FROM `availabilities` AS `Availability` LEFT JOIN `rooms` AS `Room` ON (`Availability`.`room_id` = `Room`.`id` AND `Room`.`deleted` = 0 AND `Room`.`enabled` = 1) WHERE `Availability`.`date` BETWEEN '2012-04-16 00:00:00' AND '2012-06-25 23:59:59' ORDER BY `Availability`.`date` ASC, `Room`.`list_no` ASC        602 602 5
30  SELECT `Price`.`id`, `Price`.`price`, `Price`.`availability_id`, `Price`.`rate_id` FROM `prices` AS `Price` WHERE `Price`.`availability_id` IN (16344, 14237, 14907, 14572, 13902, 15577, 15242, 15980, 13567, 16345, 14238, 14908, 14573, 13903, 15578, 15243, 15981, 13568, 16346, 14239, 14909, 14574, 13904, 13569, 15579, 15244, 15982, 16347, 14240, 13905, 14910, 14575, 13570, 15580, 15245, 15983, 16348, 14241, 13906, 14911, 14576, 13571, 15970, 15581, 15246, 16349, 14242, 14577, 13907, 14912, 13572, 15971, 15582, 15247, 16350, 14243, 14913, 14578, 13908, 13573, 15972, 15583, 15248, 16351, 14244, 14914, 14579, 13909, 15249, 13574, 15973, 15584, 16352, 14245, 14915, 14580, 13910, 15585, 15250, 13575, 15974, 16353, 14246, 14916, 14581, 13911, 15975, 15586, 15251, 13576, 16354, 14247, 14917, 14582, 13912, 13577, 15976, 15587, 15252, 16355, 14248, 13913, 14918, 14583, 13578, 15588, 15963, 15253, 16356, 14249, 13914, 14919, 14584, 13579, 15589, 15964, 15254, 16357, 14250, 14585, 13915, 14920, 13580, 15590, 15965, 15255, 16358, 14251, 14921, 14586, 13916, 13581, 15591, 15966, 15256, 16359, 14252, 14922, 14587, 13917, 15967, 15257, 13582, 15592, 16360, 14253, 14923, 14588, 13918, 15593, 15968, 15258, 13583, 16361, 14254, 14924, 14589, 13919, 15594, 15969, 15259, 13584, 16362, 14255, 14925, 14590, 13920, 13585, 15595, 15260, 15956, 16363, 14256, 13921, 14926, 14591, 13586, 15596, 15261, 15957, 16364, 14257, 13922, 14927, 14592, 13587, 15597, 15262, 15958, 16365, 14258, 14593, 13923, 14928, 15959, 13588, 15598, 15263, 16366, 14259, 14929, 14594, 13924, 15960, 13589, 15599, 15264, 16367, 14260, 14930, 14595, 13925, 15265, 15961, 13590, 15600, 16368, 14261, 14931, 14596, 13926, 15601, 15266, 15962, 13591, 16369, 14262, 14932, 14597, 13927, 15602, 15267, 15949, 13592, 16370, 14263, 14933, 14598, 13928, 13593, 15603, 15268, 15950, 16371, 14264, 13929, 14934, 14599, 15951, 13594, 15604, 15269, 16372, 14265, 13930, 14935, 14600, 15952, 13595, 15605, 15270, 16373, 14266, 14601, 13931, 14936, 15953, 13596, 15606, 15271, 16374, 14267, 14937, 14602, 13932, 15954, 13597, 15607, 15272, 16375, 14268, 14938, 14603, 13933, 15273, 15955, 13598, 15608, 16376, 14269, 14939, 14604, 13934, 15609, 15274, 13599, 15942, 16377, 14270, 14940, 14605, 13935, 15943, 15610, 15275, 13600, 14271, 14941, 14606, 13936, 13601, 15944, 15611, 15276, 14272, 13937, 14942, 14607, 13602, 15945, 15612, 15277, 14273, 13938, 14943, 14608, 13603, 15946, 15613, 15278, 14274, 14609, 13939, 14944, 13604, 15947, 15614, 15279, 14275, 14945, 14610, 13940, 13605, 15948, 15615, 15280, 14276, 14946, 14611, 13941, 15281, 15935, 13606, 15616, 14277, 14947, 14612, 13942, 15617, 15282, 15936, 13607, 14278, 14948, 14613, 13943, 15618, 15283, 15937, 13608, 14279, 14949, 14614, 13944, 13609, 15619, 15284, 15938, 14280, 13945, 14950, 14615, 13610, 15620, 15285, 15939, 14281, 13946, 14951, 14616, 13611, 15621, 15286, 15940, 14282, 14617, 13947, 14952, 13612, 15622, 15287, 15941, 14283, 14953, 14618, 13948, 15928, 13613, 15623, 15288, 14284, 14954, 14619, 13949, 15289, 15929, 13614, 15624, 14285, 14955, 14620, 13950, 15625, 15290, 15930, 13615, 14286, 14956, 14621, 13951, 15626, 15291, 15931, 13616, 14287, 14957, 14622, 13952, 13617, 15627, 15292, 15932, 14288, 13953, 14958, 14623, 13618, 15628, 15293, 15933, 14289, 13954, 14959, 14624, 13619, 15629, 15294, 15934, 14290, 14625, 13955, 14960, 15921, 13620, 15630, 15295, 14291, 14961, 14626, 13956, 15922, 13621, 15631, 15296, 14292, 14962, 14627, 13957, 15297, 15923, 13622, 15632, 14293, 14963, 14628, 13958, 15633, 15298, 15924, 13623, 14294, 14964, 14629, 13959, 15634, 15299, 15925, 13624, 14295, 14965, 14630, 13960, 13625, 15635, 15300, 15926, 14296, 13961, 14966, 14631, 15927, 13626, 15636, 15301, 14297, 13962, 14967, 14632, 13627, 15914, 15637, 15302, 14298, 14633, 13963, 14968, 13628, 15915, 15638, 15303, 14299, 14969, 14634, 13964, 13629, 15916, 15639, 15304, 14300, 14970, 14635, 13965, 15305, 13630, 15917, 15640, 14301, 14971, 14636, 13966, 15641, 15306, 13631, 15918, 14302, 14972, 14637, 13967, 15919, 15642, 15307, 13632, 14303, 14973, 14638, 13968, 13633, 15920, 15643, 15308, 14304, 13969, 14974, 14639, 13634, 15644, 15309, 15907, 14305, 13970, 14975, 14640, 15908, 13635, 15645, 15310, 14306, 14641, 13971, 14976, 15909, 13636, 15646, 15311, 14307, 14977, 14642, 13972, 15910, 13637, 15647, 15312)       1529    1529    7
31  SELECT `BookingOrder`.`id`, `BookingOrder`.`booking_id`, `BookingOrder`.`rate_id`, `BookingOrder`.`room_id`, `BookingOrder`.`occupancy`, `BookingOrder`.`children`, `BookingOrder`.`supplement`, `BookingOrder`.`price`, `BookingOrder`.`total_room_price`, `BookingOrder`.`add_on_price`, `BookingOrder`.`date_from`, `BookingOrder`.`date_to`, `BookingOrder`.`comments`, `BookingOrder`.`created`, `BookingOrder`.`updated`, `BookingOrder`.`status`, `BookingOrder`.`cancelled`, `AvailabilitiesBookingOrder`.`id`, `AvailabilitiesBookingOrder`.`availability_id`, `AvailabilitiesBookingOrder`.`booking_order_id` FROM `booking_orders` AS `BookingOrder` JOIN `availabilities_booking_orders` AS `AvailabilitiesBookingOrder` ON (`AvailabilitiesBookingOrder`.`availability_id` IN (16344, 14237, 14907, 14572, 13902, 15577, 15242, 15980, 13567, 16345, 14238, 14908, 14573, 13903, 15578, 15243, 15981, 13568, 16346, 14239, 14909, 14574, 13904, 13569, 15579, 15244, 15982, 16347, 14240, 13905, 14910, 14575, 13570, 15580, 15245, 15983, 16348, 14241, 13906, 14911, 14576, 13571, 15970, 15581, 15246, 16349, 14242, 14577, 13907, 14912, 13572, 15971, 15582, 15247, 16350, 14243, 14913, 14578, 13908, 13573, 15972, 15583, 15248, 16351, 14244, 14914, 14579, 13909, 15249, 13574, 15973, 15584, 16352, 14245, 14915, 14580, 13910, 15585, 15250, 13575, 15974, 16353, 14246, 14916, 14581, 13911, 15975, 15586, 15251, 13576, 16354, 14247, 14917, 14582, 13912, 13577, 15976, 15587, 15252, 16355, 14248, 13913, 14918, 14583, 13578, 15588, 15963, 15253, 16356, 14249, 13914, 14919, 14584, 13579, 15589, 15964, 15254, 16357, 14250, 14585, 13915, 14920, 13580, 15590, 15965, 15255, 16358, 14251, 14921, 14586, 13916, 13581, 15591, 15966, 15256, 16359, 14252, 14922, 14587, 13917, 15967, 15257, 13582, 15592, 16360, 14253, 14923, 14588, 13918, 15593, 15968, 15258, 13583, 16361, 14254, 14924, 14589, 13919, 15594, 15969, 15259, 13584, 16362, 14255, 14925, 14590, 13920, 13585, 15595, 15260, 15956, 16363, 14256, 13921, 14926, 14591, 13586, 15596, 15261, 15957, 16364, 14257, 13922, 14927, 14592, 13587, 15597, 15262, 15958, 16365, 14258, 14593, 13923, 14928, 15959, 13588, 15598, 15263, 16366, 14259, 14929, 14594, 13924, 15960, 13589, 15599, 15264, 16367, 14260, 14930, 14595, 13925, 15265, 15961, 13590, 15600, 16368, 14261, 14931, 14596, 13926, 15601, 15266, 15962, 13591, 16369, 14262, 14932, 14597, 13927, 15602, 15267, 15949, 13592, 16370, 14263, 14933, 14598, 13928, 13593, 15603, 15268, 15950, 16371, 14264, 13929, 14934, 14599, 15951, 13594, 15604, 15269, 16372, 14265, 13930, 14935, 14600, 15952, 13595, 15605, 15270, 16373, 14266, 14601, 13931, 14936, 15953, 13596, 15606, 15271, 16374, 14267, 14937, 14602, 13932, 15954, 13597, 15607, 15272, 16375, 14268, 14938, 14603, 13933, 15273, 15955, 13598, 15608, 16376, 14269, 14939, 14604, 13934, 15609, 15274, 13599, 15942, 16377, 14270, 14940, 14605, 13935, 15943, 15610, 15275, 13600, 14271, 14941, 14606, 13936, 13601, 15944, 15611, 15276, 14272, 13937, 14942, 14607, 13602, 15945, 15612, 15277, 14273, 13938, 14943, 14608, 13603, 15946, 15613, 15278, 14274, 14609, 13939, 14944, 13604, 15947, 15614, 15279, 14275, 14945, 14610, 13940, 13605, 15948, 15615, 15280, 14276, 14946, 14611, 13941, 15281, 15935, 13606, 15616, 14277, 14947, 14612, 13942, 15617, 15282, 15936, 13607, 14278, 14948, 14613, 13943, 15618, 15283, 15937, 13608, 14279, 14949, 14614, 13944, 13609, 15619, 15284, 15938, 14280, 13945, 14950, 14615, 13610, 15620, 15285, 15939, 14281, 13946, 14951, 14616, 13611, 15621, 15286, 15940, 14282, 14617, 13947, 14952, 13612, 15622, 15287, 15941, 14283, 14953, 14618, 13948, 15928, 13613, 15623, 15288, 14284, 14954, 14619, 13949, 15289, 15929, 13614, 15624, 14285, 14955, 14620, 13950, 15625, 15290, 15930, 13615, 14286, 14956, 14621, 13951, 15626, 15291, 15931, 13616, 14287, 14957, 14622, 13952, 13617, 15627, 15292, 15932, 14288, 13953, 14958, 14623, 13618, 15628, 15293, 15933, 14289, 13954, 14959, 14624, 13619, 15629, 15294, 15934, 14290, 14625, 13955, 14960, 15921, 13620, 15630, 15295, 14291, 14961, 14626, 13956, 15922, 13621, 15631, 15296, 14292, 14962, 14627, 13957, 15297, 15923, 13622, 15632, 14293, 14963, 14628, 13958, 15633, 15298, 15924, 13623, 14294, 14964, 14629, 13959, 15634, 15299, 15925, 13624, 14295, 14965, 14630, 13960, 13625, 15635, 15300, 15926, 14296, 13961, 14966, 14631, 15927, 13626, 15636, 15301, 14297, 13962, 14967, 14632, 13627, 15914, 15637, 15302, 14298, 14633, 13963, 14968, 13628, 15915, 15638, 15303, 14299, 14969, 14634, 13964, 13629, 15916, 15639, 15304, 14300, 14970, 14635, 13965, 15305, 13630, 15917, 15640, 14301, 14971, 14636, 13966, 15641, 15306, 13631, 15918, 14302, 14972, 14637, 13967, 15919, 15642, 15307, 13632, 14303, 14973, 14638, 13968, 13633, 15920, 15643, 15308, 14304, 13969, 14974, 14639, 13634, 15644, 15309, 15907, 14305, 13970, 14975, 14640, 15908, 13635, 15645, 15310, 14306, 14641, 13971, 14976, 15909, 13636, 15646, 15311, 14307, 14977, 14642, 13972, 15910, 13637, 15647, 15312) AND `AvailabilitiesBookingOrder`.`booking_order_id` = `BookingOrder`.`id`) WHERE `BookingOrder`.`cancelled` = 0       0   0   2
32  SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `bookings_x`     31  31  5
33  SELECT `Xbooking`.`id` FROM `bookings_x` AS `Xbooking` WHERE `Xbooking`.`token` = 't9ZhP1x' LIMIT 1     0   0   6
34  INSERT INTO `bookings_x` (`booking_id`, `arrival`, `ip_address`, `json_dump`, `token`, `request_src`, `res_action`, `updated`, `created`) VALUES (0, '2012-04-16', '127.0.0.1', '{\"Availability\":{\"2012-04-16\":{\"27\":\"16344\",\"12\":\"14237\",\"11\":\"14907\",\"14\":\"14572\",\"15\":\"13902\",\"18\":\"15577\",\"17\":\"15242\",\"13\":\"15980\",\"16\":\"13567\"},\"2012-04-17\":{\"27\":\"16345\",\"12\":\"14238\",\"11\":\"14908\",\"14\":\"14573\",\"15\":\"13903\",\"18\":\"15578\",\"17\":\"15243\",\"13\":\"15981\",\"16\":\"13568\"},\"2012-04-18\":{\"27\":\"16346\",\"12\":\"14239\",\"11\":\"14909\",\"14\":\"14574\",\"15\":\"13904\",\"16\":\"13569\",\"18\":\"15579\",\"17\":\"15244\",\"13\":\"15982\"},\"2012-04-19\":{\"27\":\"16347\",\"12\":\"14240\",\"15\":\"13905\",\"11\":\"14910\",\"14\":\"14575\",\"16\":\"13570\",\"18\":\"15580\",\"17\":\"15245\",\"13\":\"15983\"},\"2012-04-20\":{\"27\":\"16348\",\"12\":\"14241\",\"15\":\"13906\",\"11\":\"14911\",\"14\":\"14576\",\"16\":\"13571\",\"13\":\"15970\",\"18\":\"15581\",\"17\":\"15246\"},\"2012-04-21\":{\"27\":\"16349\",\"12\":\"14242\",\"14\":\"14577\",\"15\":\"13907\",\"11\":\"14912\",\"16\":\"13572\",\"13\":\"15971\",\"18\":\"15582\",\"17\":\"15247\"},\"2012-04-22\":{\"27\":\"16350\",\"12\":\"14243\",\"11\":\"14913\",\"14\":\"14578\",\"15\":\"13908\",\"16\":\"13573\",\"13\":\"15972\",\"18\":\"15583\",\"17\":\"15248\"},\"2012-04-23\":{\"27\":\"16351\",\"12\":\"14244\",\"11\":\"14914\",\"14\":\"14579\",\"15\":\"13909\",\"17\":\"15249\",\"16\":\"13574\",\"13\":\"15973\",\"18\":\"15584\"},\"2012-04-24\":{\"27\":\"16352\",\"12\":\"14245\",\"11\":\"14915\",\"14\":\"14580\",\"15\":\"13910\",\"18\":\"15585\",\"17\":\"15250\",\"16\":\"13575\",\"13\":\"15974\"},\"2012-04-25\":{\"27\":\"16353\",\"12\":\"14246\",\"11\":\"14916\",\"14\":\"14581\",\"15\":\"13911\",\"13\":\"15975\",\"18\":\"15586\",\"17\":\"15251\",\"16\":\"13576\"},\"2012-04-26\":{\"27\":\"16354\",\"12\":\"14247\",\"11\":\"14917\",\"14\":\"14582\",\"15\":\"13912\",\"16\":\"13577\",\"13\":\"15976\",\"18\":\"15587\",\"17\":\"15252\"},\"2012-04-27\":{\"27\":\"16355\",\"12\":\"14248\",\"15\":\"13913\",\"11\":\"14918\",\"14\":\"14583\",\"16\":\"13578\",\"18\":\"15588\",\"13\":\"15963\",\"17\":\"15253\"},\"2012-04-28\":{\"27\":\"16356\",\"12\":\"14249\",\"15\":\"13914\",\"11\":\"14919\",\"14\":\"14584\",\"16\":\"13579\",\"18\":\"15589\",\"13\":\"15964\",\"17\":\"15254\"},\"2012-04-29\":{\"27\":\"16357\",\"12\":\"14250\",\"14\":\"14585\",\"15\":\"13915\",\"11\":\"14920\",\"16\":\"13580\",\"18\":\"15590\",\"13\":\"15965\",\"17\":\"15255\"},\"2012-04-30\":{\"27\":\"16358\",\"12\":\"14251\",\"11\":\"14921\",\"14\":\"14586\",\"15\":\"13916\",\"16\":\"13581\",\"18\":\"15591\",\"13\":\"15966\",\"17\":\"15256\"},\"2012-05-01\":{\"27\":\"16359\",\"12\":\"14252\",\"11\":\"14922\",\"14\":\"14587\",\"15\":\"13917\",\"13\":\"15967\",\"17\":\"15257\",\"16\":\"13582\",\"18\":\"15592\"},\"2012-05-02\":{\"27\":\"16360\",\"12\":\"14253\",\"11\":\"14923\",\"14\":\"14588\",\"15\":\"13918\",\"18\":\"15593\",\"13\":\"15968\",\"17\":\"15258\",\"16\":\"13583\"},\"2012-05-03\":{\"27\":\"16361\",\"12\":\"14254\",\"11\":\"14924\",\"14\":\"14589\",\"15\":\"13919\",\"18\":\"15594\",\"13\":\"15969\",\"17\":\"15259\",\"16\":\"13584\"},\"2012-05-04\":{\"27\":\"16362\",\"12\":\"14255\",\"11\":\"14925\",\"14\":\"14590\",\"15\":\"13920\",\"16\":\"13585\",\"18\":\"15595\",\"17\":\"15260\",\"13\":\"15956\"},\"2012-05-05\":{\"27\":\"16363\",\"12\":\"14256\",\"15\":\"13921\",\"11\":\"14926\",\"14\":\"14591\",\"16\":\"13586\",\"18\":\"15596\",\"17\":\"15261\",\"13\":\"15957\"},\"2012-05-06\":{\"27\":\"16364\",\"12\":\"14257\",\"15\":\"13922\",\"11\":\"14927\",\"14\":\"14592\",\"16\":\"13587\",\"18\":\"15597\",\"17\":\"15262\",\"13\":\"15958\"},\"2012-05-07\":{\"27\":\"16365\",\"12\":\"14258\",\"14\":\"14593\",\"15\":\"13923\",\"11\":\"14928\",\"13\":\"15959\",\"16\":\"13588\",\"18\":\"15598\",\"17\":\"15263\"},\"2012-05-08\":{\"27\":\"16366\",\"12\":\"14259\",\"11\":\"14929\",\"14\":\"14594\",\"15\":\"13924\",\"13\":\"15960\",\"16\":\"13589\",\"18\":\"15599\",\"17\":\"15264\"},\"2012-05-09\":{\"27\":\"16367\",\"12\":\"14260\",\"11\":\"14930\",\"14\":\"14595\",\"15\":\"13925\",\"17\":\"15265\",\"13\":\"15961\",\"16\":\"13590\",\"18\":\"15600\"},\"2012-05-10\":{\"27\":\"16368\",\"12\":\"14261\",\"11\":\"14931\",\"14\":\"14596\",\"15\":\"13926\",\"18\":\"15601\",\"17\":\"15266\",\"13\":\"15962\",\"16\":\"13591\"},\"2012-05-11\":{\"27\":\"16369\",\"12\":\"14262\",\"11\":\"14932\",\"14\":\"14597\",\"15\":\"13927\",\"18\":\"15602\",\"17\":\"15267\",\"13\":\"15949\",\"16\":\"13592\"},\"2012-05-12\":{\"27\":\"16370\",\"12\":\"14263\",\"11\":\"14933\",\"14\":\"14598\",\"15\":\"13928\",\"16\":\"13593\",\"18\":\"15603\",\"17\":\"15268\",\"13\":\"15950\"},\"2012-05-13\":{\"27\":\"16371\",\"12\":\"14264\",\"15\":\"13929\",\"11\":\"14934\",\"14\":\"14599\",\"13\":\"15951\",\"16\":\"13594\",\"18\":\"15604\",\"17\":\"15269\"},\"2012-05-14\":{\"27\":\"16372\",\"12\":\"14265\",\"15\":\"13930\",\"11\":\"14935\",\"14\":\"14600\",\"13\":\"15952\",\"16\":\"13595\",\"18\":\"15605\",\"17\":\"15270\"},\"2012-05-15\":{\"27\":\"16373\",\"12\":\"14266\",\"14\":\"14601\",\"15\":\"13931\",\"11\":\"14936\",\"13\":\"15953\",\"16\":\"13596\",\"18\":\"15606\",\"17\":\"15271\"},\"2012-05-16\":{\"27\":\"16374\",\"12\":\"14267\",\"11\":\"14937\",\"14\":\"14602\",\"15\":\"13932\",\"13\":\"15954\",\"16\":\"13597\",\"18\":\"15607\",\"17\":\"15272\"},\"2012-05-17\":{\"27\":\"16375\",\"12\":\"14268\",\"11\":\"14938\",\"14\":\"14603\",\"15\":\"13933\",\"17\":\"15273\",\"13\":\"15955\",\"16\":\"13598\",\"18\":\"15608\"},\"2012-05-18\":{\"27\":\"16376\",\"12\":\"14269\",\"11\":\"14939\",\"14\":\"14604\",\"15\":\"13934\",\"18\":\"15609\",\"17\":\"15274\",\"16\":\"13599\",\"13\":\"15942\"},\"2012-05-19\":{\"27\":\"16377\",\"12\":\"14270\",\"11\":\"14940\",\"14\":\"14605\",\"15\":\"13935\",\"13\":\"15943\",\"18\":\"15610\",\"17\":\"15275\",\"16\":\"13600\"},\"2012-05-20\":{\"12\":\"14271\",\"11\":\"14941\",\"14\":\"14606\",\"15\":\"13936\",\"16\":\"13601\",\"13\":\"15944\",\"18\":\"15611\",\"17\":\"15276\"},\"2012-05-21\":{\"12\":\"14272\",\"15\":\"13937\",\"11\":\"14942\",\"14\":\"14607\",\"16\":\"13602\",\"13\":\"15945\",\"18\":\"15612\",\"17\":\"15277\"},\"2012-05-22\":{\"12\":\"14273\",\"15\":\"13938\",\"11\":\"14943\",\"14\":\"14608\",\"16\":\"13603\",\"13\":\"15946\",\"18\":\"15613\",\"17\":\"15278\"},\"2012-05-23\":{\"12\":\"14274\",\"14\":\"14609\",\"15\":\"13939\",\"11\":\"14944\",\"16\":\"13604\",\"13\":\"15947\",\"18\":\"15614\",\"17\":\"15279\"},\"2012-05-24\":{\"12\":\"14275\",\"11\":\"14945\",\"14\":\"14610\",\"15\":\"13940\",\"16\":\"13605\",\"13\":\"15948\",\"18\":\"15615\",\"17\":\"15280\"},\"2012-05-25\":{\"12\":\"14276\",\"11\":\"14946\",\"14\":\"14611\",\"15\":\"13941\",\"17\":\"15281\",\"13\":\"15935\",\"16\":\"13606\",\"18\":\"15616\"},\"2012-05-26\":{\"12\":\"14277\",\"11\":\"14947\",\"14\":\"14612\",\"15\":\"13942\",\"18\":\"15617\",\"17\":\"15282\",\"13\":\"15936\",\"16\":\"13607\"},\"2012-05-27\":{\"12\":\"14278\",\"11\":\"14948\",\"14\":\"14613\",\"15\":\"13943\",\"18\":\"15618\",\"17\":\"15283\",\"13\":\"15937\",\"16\":\"13608\"},\"2012-05-28\":{\"12\":\"14279\",\"11\":\"14949\",\"14\":\"14614\",\"15\":\"13944\",\"16\":\"13609\",\"18\":\"15619\",\"17\":\"15284\",\"13\":\"15938\"},\"2012-05-29\":{\"12\":\"14280\",\"15\":\"13945\",\"11\":\"14950\",\"14\":\"14615\",\"16\":\"13610\",\"18\":\"15620\",\"17\":\"15285\",\"13\":\"15939\"},\"2012-05-30\":{\"12\":\"14281\",\"15\":\"13946\",\"11\":\"14951\",\"14\":\"14616\",\"16\":\"13611\",\"18\":\"15621\",\"17\":\"15286\",\"13\":\"15940\"},\"2012-05-31\":{\"12\":\"14282\",\"14\":\"14617\",\"15\":\"13947\",\"11\":\"14952\",\"16\":\"13612\",\"18\":\"15622\",\"17\":\"15287\",\"13\":\"15941\"},\"2012-06-01\":{\"12\":\"14283\",\"11\":\"14953\",\"14\":\"14618\",\"15\":\"13948\",\"13\":\"15928\",\"16\":\"13613\",\"18\":\"15623\",\"17\":\"15288\"},\"2012-06-02\":{\"12\":\"14284\",\"11\":\"14954\",\"14\":\"14619\",\"15\":\"13949\",\"17\":\"15289\",\"13\":\"15929\",\"16\":\"13614\",\"18\":\"15624\"},\"2012-06-03\":{\"12\":\"14285\",\"11\":\"14955\",\"14\":\"14620\",\"15\":\"13950\",\"18\":\"15625\",\"17\":\"15290\",\"13\":\"15930\",\"16\":\"13615\"},\"2012-06-04\":{\"12\":\"14286\",\"11\":\"14956\",\"14\":\"14621\",\"15\":\"13951\",\"18\":\"15626\",\"17\":\"15291\",\"13\":\"15931\",\"16\":\"13616\"},\"2012-06-05\":{\"12\":\"14287\",\"11\":\"14957\",\"14\":\"14622\",\"15\":\"13952\",\"16\":\"13617\",\"18\":\"15627\",\"17\":\"15292\",\"13\":\"15932\"},\"2012-06-06\":{\"12\":\"14288\",\"15\":\"13953\",\"11\":\"14958\",\"14\":\"14623\",\"16\":\"13618\",\"18\":\"15628\",\"17\":\"15293\",\"13\":\"15933\"},\"2012-06-07\":{\"12\":\"14289\",\"15\":\"13954\",\"11\":\"14959\",\"14\":\"14624\",\"16\":\"13619\",\"18\":\"15629\",\"17\":\"15294\",\"13\":\"15934\"},\"2012-06-08\":{\"12\":\"14290\",\"14\":\"14625\",\"15\":\"13955\",\"11\":\"14960\",\"13\":\"15921\",\"16\":\"13620\",\"18\":\"15630\",\"17\":\"15295\"},\"2012-06-09\":{\"12\":\"14291\",\"11\":\"14961\",\"14\":\"14626\",\"15\":\"13956\",\"13\":\"15922\",\"16\":\"13621\",\"18\":\"15631\",\"17\":\"15296\"},\"2012-06-10\":{\"12\":\"14292\",\"11\":\"14962\",\"14\":\"14627\",\"15\":\"13957\",\"17\":\"15297\",\"13\":\"15923\",\"16\":\"13622\",\"18\":\"15632\"},\"2012-06-11\":{\"12\":\"14293\",\"11\":\"14963\",\"14\":\"14628\",\"15\":\"13958\",\"18\":\"15633\",\"17\":\"15298\",\"13\":\"15924\",\"16\":\"13623\"},\"2012-06-12\":{\"12\":\"14294\",\"11\":\"14964\",\"14\":\"14629\",\"15\":\"13959\",\"18\":\"15634\",\"17\":\"15299\",\"13\":\"15925\",\"16\":\"13624\"},\"2012-06-13\":{\"12\":\"14295\",\"11\":\"14965\",\"14\":\"14630\",\"15\":\"13960\",\"16\":\"13625\",\"18\":\"15635\",\"17\":\"15300\",\"13\":\"15926\"},\"2012-06-14\":{\"12\":\"14296\",\"15\":\"13961\",\"11\":\"14966\",\"14\":\"14631\",\"13\":\"15927\",\"16\":\"13626\",\"18\":\"15636\",\"17\":\"15301\"},\"2012-06-15\":{\"12\":\"14297\",\"15\":\"13962\",\"11\":\"14967\",\"14\":\"14632\",\"16\":\"13627\",\"13\":\"15914\",\"18\":\"15637\",\"17\":\"15302\"},\"2012-06-16\":{\"12\":\"14298\",\"14\":\"14633\",\"15\":\"13963\",\"11\":\"14968\",\"16\":\"13628\",\"13\":\"15915\",\"18\":\"15638\",\"17\":\"15303\"},\"2012-06-17\":{\"12\":\"14299\",\"11\":\"14969\",\"14\":\"14634\",\"15\":\"13964\",\"16\":\"13629\",\"13\":\"15916\",\"18\":\"15639\",\"17\":\"15304\"},\"2012-06-18\":{\"12\":\"14300\",\"11\":\"14970\",\"14\":\"14635\",\"15\":\"13965\",\"17\":\"15305\",\"16\":\"13630\",\"13\":\"15917\",\"18\":\"15640\"},\"2012-06-19\":{\"12\":\"14301\",\"11\":\"14971\",\"14\":\"14636\",\"15\":\"13966\",\"18\":\"15641\",\"17\":\"15306\",\"16\":\"13631\",\"13\":\"15918\"},\"2012-06-20\":{\"12\":\"14302\",\"11\":\"14972\",\"14\":\"14637\",\"15\":\"13967\",\"13\":\"15919\",\"18\":\"15642\",\"17\":\"15307\",\"16\":\"13632\"},\"2012-06-21\":{\"12\":\"14303\",\"11\":\"14973\",\"14\":\"14638\",\"15\":\"13968\",\"16\":\"13633\",\"13\":\"15920\",\"18\":\"15643\",\"17\":\"15308\"},\"2012-06-22\":{\"12\":\"14304\",\"15\":\"13969\",\"11\":\"14974\",\"14\":\"14639\",\"16\":\"13634\",\"18\":\"15644\",\"17\":\"15309\",\"13\":\"15907\"},\"2012-06-23\":{\"12\":\"14305\",\"15\":\"13970\",\"11\":\"14975\",\"14\":\"14640\",\"13\":\"15908\",\"16\":\"13635\",\"18\":\"15645\",\"17\":\"15310\"},\"2012-06-24\":{\"12\":\"14306\",\"14\":\"14641\",\"15\":\"13971\",\"11\":\"14976\",\"13\":\"15909\",\"16\":\"13636\",\"18\":\"15646\",\"17\":\"15311\"},\"2012-06-25\":{\"12\":\"14307\",\"11\":\"14977\",\"14\":\"14642\",\"15\":\"13972\",\"13\":\"15910\",\"16\":\"13637\",\"18\":\"15647\",\"17\":\"15312\"}},\"Vouchers\":[],\"Rate\":0,\"Addons\":[]}', 't9ZhP1x', 'website', 'availability', '2012-03-16 11:15:06', '2012-03-16 11:15:06')       1       1
35  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS insertID
```

I'm not sure how to translate all of this into a MySQL query...

Comment: Why do you need to do that ? What will the SQL query be used for ?

Answer (score 2):

Set debug level to 2 in core.php. The MySQL queries are displayed at the bottom of the page and you can just copy-paste the exact query CakePHP generates.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your project setup, sometimes it is not in the exact core.php as Juhana mentioned, but it should be somewhere in the config section you sure can find out.

In case you don't want to use the builtin find function, you can leave your query in a user function defined in some related model where you can make a call to it via `$this->query(yoursql);`

Answer (score 0):

Mine is not the right way, but anyways i got what i needed.
This is what i did,
taking your cake query as an example, i purposely made a spelling mistake while writing conditions in the cake query. Hence my mysql returned an SQL error in which the entire query was re written in mysql format. Just copied this query, changed the spelling mistake in it and used it.
Hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @vin.it but that doesn't output the MySQL on my setup, I only get 'SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM' listings